# How to make something similar to rigid body joint in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, armature, rigid-body-simulation

[image]

So I made a ragdoll horse in the Game engine using an armature and some hitboxes. I connected these hitboxes with Rigid Body Joints. Now I want to use this rig for animation. However, I animate with Cycles. I know that the Rigid Body Joint does not work in Cycles, and the Rigid Body Constraint set on Hinge in the physics tab doesn't do the same thing- it just stays rigid and doesn't swivel. Is there any way to get the same effect that I get with Rigid Body Joint, but in Cycles?

Comment: I don’t understand... cycles does support rigid body constraints and they should work fine - although you may need to recreate them while in Cycles mode rather than trying to use those that were created in the game engine as they aren’t compatible.

Comment: I already tried that, however, when I add a Rigid Body Constraint to two hitboxes, they fall through each other and don't collide.

Comment: What should I do? I've tried everything I can think of, but they just won't collide.

Comment: Rigid Body Constraints disable collisions with their neighbours by default - you have to switch a checkbox in the physics properties to enable it. Failing that, can you post your Blend file to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and edit your question to paste the link.

Comment: Oh! Duh. I should have seen that. Thank you!

Comment: No worries - glad it’s working now. I’ve added an answer for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

The game engine rigid body joints do not work outside the game engine. For similar behaviour in Cycles you should use [Rigid Body Constraints](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/rigid_body/constraints/introduction.html#common-options) - these can be created by selecting two or more rigid bodies and clicking Connect in the Physics Toolbox panel (<kbd>T</kbd>). When a rigid body constraint is first added it defaults to ‘Disable Collision’ - to enable collision between linked objects you should untick the checkbox in the Rigid Body Constraint physics properties.